# Using a parameter for IN in a tableadapter query

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, parameter-passing

I have a query in a myTableAdapter that ends with WHERE column IN (@S).  This works fine when I use myTableAdapter.Fill(dataset.table, "text") but I can't find any way that works to provide multiple text strings such as "text1, text2" for the IN parameter.  How can this be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause, look at the 2nd answer, it's better I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible as it stands as far as I know.

The alternative is to use dynamic SQL (i.e. generate the `WHERE` clause in code), but this is bad practice unless you really don't care about security, maintainability or readability!

The other extreme involves writing a table-valued function to live on the db server that accepts your `@S` parameter. 
This param should be a delimited string which you could then parse within the function using T-SQL `WHILE` and `BEGIN ... END` constructs, inserting each item from your string into a temp table.

Finally, your query's `WHERE` clause would then become something like:

```
WHERE myField in (SELECT myTempColumn from [dbo].[myParsingFunction] (@S))
```

Comment: the coment above from manji pretty much takes care of this.  Thanks.